# Using multiple div id's with same piece of script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onchange

I have several select boxes on a page, and basically anytime an onchange event occurs with any of those boxes I want to use the same piece of code instead of making a separate script for each select box's id. The reason is that I could be ending up with dozens of these select boxes on a page and all that repeated code just gets messy.

```
<select name="drop_list_menu_1" id="drop_list_menu_1">
<option value="letter:a">A</option>
<option value="letter:b">B</option>
<option value="letter:c">C</option>
</select>

<select name="drop_list_menu_2" id="drop_list_menu_2">
<option value="letter:a">A</option>
<option value="letter:b">B</option>
<option value="letter:c">C</option>
</select>

<select name="drop_list_menu_3" id="drop_list_menu_3">
<option value="letter:a">A</option>
<option value="letter:b">B</option>
<option value="letter:c">C</option>
</select>
```

My code to handle the onchange event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            // if user chooses an option from the select box...
            $("#drop_list_menu_1").change(function () {

                //doin some stuff
            }); 

</script>
```

So, how can I get this:

```
$("#drop_list_menu_1").change(function () {

                    //doin some stuff
                });
```

to catch any of the select boxes on the page being used? Something incorporating a regex?

Comment: IDs are supposed to be used for singular elements, if you need multiple, adding a class would be more appropriate. Can you do that or can you not touch the HTML?

Comment: So, I went ahead and added a class="drop" to my selectors. And, there are a couple of other non-related select boxes on the page making the class association the only option. I then tried all your answers and WPFRookie's answer was the only one that worked. Thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign same class to each Select and call it as below.

```
$(".ClassName").change(function (e) {
      var SelectId = e.target.id
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the elements a common class (you can keep the id attributes if you want) and then use delegation:

```
$(document).on("change", "your-select-class", function() {
  var changedElement = this;
  // ...
});
```

You just need that one call to set up the event handler, and it'll work for as many copies as you need on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jQuery's attribute starts-with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to select all drop-downs whose name begins with "*drop_list_menu_*":

```
$("select[name^='drop_list_menu_']").change(function(){
    //doin some stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

simple as that

```
$("select").change(function () {

    alert('a');
});
```

Comment: Not useful, if there are more `select`s on the page. It may be the case that they get added in the future, for example.

Comment: This piece of code would attach the same event handler to all `select` elements on the page. OP currently shows three of them but that might not be the case in the real page. And even if it is, in the future the page could be changed to add another one. If the new `select` is not required to have the same event handler attached to it, it may mean the page would be broken.

Comment: ah of course i thought you have something else in mind, well this is exactly  for this particular case w/t other conditions but thanks anyway